# Three-dimensional triangulations with fixed number of vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, 3-manifolds, triangulations

My question is the following:

> Are there triangulations of $S^3$ which (a) are non-degenerate, (b)
> have four vertices, and (c) have no edges of degree two?

A side question:

> If one represents this triangulation as a graph, and draws it's dual graph, is it true that it is a planar graph?

(At the moment I'm unable to construct a planar graph starting from an edge degree 6 or 8 with the above requirements and taking into account the comments , that all degrees are even, as I end up with growing number of tetrahedra.)

---

Here are the definitions.

We use labeled triangulations of $S^3$.  We allow adjacent tetrahedra to share multiple faces. The *degree* of a vertex (or an edge) is the number of tetrahedra connected to it, *counted with multiplicity*.

We only allow *non-degenerate triangulations*.  That is, we require that every edge is embedded (meets two vertices).  Note that this implies that all triangles and tetrahedra are embedded.

However, we do not require our triangulations to be *simplicial* (where a cell is determined by its vertices).  In particular, we allow many edges to share the same two endpoints as vertices.  In this case we distinguish the edges by their labels.  The same applies to triangles and tetrahedra.

There are various moves that can change the configuration to another.  To be concrete, imagine two adjacent tetrahedra defined by vertices $\{a, b, c, d\}$ sharing four faces.  Note that all edges have degree two. Let's call this our "initial configuration".  We can add additional tetrahedra to the initial configuration (maintaining the topology) in various ways.

**0-2 face move:**
Choose a triangle (between two tetrahedra $A$ and $B$) and glue in a pair of tetrahedra ($C$ and $D$) sharing three faces, (and a new vertex: $e$), and their remaining face is glued between let's say the triangle $(a b c)$ and its copy $(a,b,c)$, defining the set now as: $\{a b c d\}$, $\{a b c d\}$, $\{a b c e\}$, $\{a b c e\}$.  This is like inflating a triangle into a sphere and putting a vertex in the middle. The same vertices can define unique triangles and edges. If we would give labels to triangle $(a b c)$ or the other $(a b c)$ they would differ due to their adjacency relation. This move increases the number of vertices.

**1-4 move:**
Choose a tetrahedron.  Add a vertex in the middle of the tetrahedron, connecting it to all the four vertices, splitting the interior into 4 tetrahedra.

**2-3 move**
Choose a face meeting distinct tetrahedra. Add an edge to connect the distant vertices of two adjacent tetrahedra, exchanging a triangular face with an edge.  This turns two tetrahedra into three.

**0-2 edge move:**
Choose two adjacent triangles $(a b c)$, $(a b d)$, and open them up, inserting two tetrahedra $\{a b c d\}$ and $\{a b c d\}$, by creating a copy of $(a b c)$ and $(a b d)$ in the process. The move adds two tetrahedra, a new edge with degree 2, and splits the original [a b] edge into be two with smaller or equal degree than their original. (0-2 edge move)

One could devise other type of moves, adding extra edges, adding/ removing extra vertices, to change the triangulation into another one.  (Note that all moves can be obtained from the [bistellar flips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachner_moves): the 2-3 and 1-4 moves.)

Comment: You might want to search the term "simplicial poset." It captures (in an abstract, combinatorial way- not geometrically) the idea of simplicial complex where multiple simplices can be defined the same sets of vertices.

Comment: I think I would be interested in simplical complexes. Every vertex and link belongs to at least two tetrahedra, and triangle precisely to two. These posets seem to be more general structures.

Comment: @Kregnach: certainly simplicial posets are “general structures,” but their definition is very simple (every interval from the minimum to any element is a Boolean lattice) and as I explained above I think they exactly capture the rules you want to allow.

Comment: I have edited your question for grammar and phrasing.  I have also changed a few more instances of "link" into "edge".  The only serious change I made is that I altered the definition of "degree" to the standard one.  That is: the degree counts the number of adjacent tetrahedra *with multiplicity*.  (This does not effect anything in your overall question.)

Comment: I don't understand the remark "Note that this implies that all triangles and tetrahedra are embedded." It seems to me you also want to explicitly disallow, e.g., filled-in digons. In other words, you must require for each $n$ that every $n$-cell contain $n+1$ vertices (which is what simplicial posets - alias Boolean complexes - do).

Comment: When I read the edit of Sam Nead (who did a great job at it, thank you! ) the embedded part also caught my attention. I am not sure what embedded means here, but as far as I know, my triangulations cannot be embedded in 3 dimensional space, so they are not embedded triangulations. But maybe here it means something else.

Comment: @Kregnach - "Embedded" means "the characteristic map is an embedding".  For example, when a triangulation has only one vertex, none of the edges are embedded, because the image of the characteristic map is a loop. (Here the "characteristic map" is from a model edge, homeomorphic to the standard unit interval, into the three-sphere.)

Comment: @SamHopkins - This is a triangulation.  Thus all "model cells" are simplices - that is, points, intervals, triangles, tetrahedra - and all characteristic maps are embeddings when restricted to their interior.  So no digons (or squares or etc) are allowed as 2-cells - just triangles.

Comment: @SamNead: my concern is that you have a degenerate triangle which has the same edge “twice” and thus becomes a digon when geometrically realized (just like you don’t want to have an edge which has a vertex twice and thus becomes a loop when geometrically realized).

Comment: @SamNead: also, maybe more standard terminology than “embedded” would be “regular,” i.e., the corresponding cell complex is regular. I’m pretty sure a regular cell complex whose cells are all simplicial is the same thing as a Boolean complex/simplicial poset.

Comment: @SamHopkins If a triangle has the same edge "twice" then either that edge is a loop (not allowed) or the third edge of the triangle is a loop (not allowed).  I agree that if all edges are embedded then the corresponding cell complex is regular.  I also agree that simplicial posets are a fine formalism for all of this.  However, I just prefer the (slightly less formal but slightly simpler, at least to me) language of triangulations: CW complexes where all cells are modelled on simplices and where all attaching maps are modelled on isomorphisms of simplices.

Comment: @Kregnach - it is bad form to add more questions to a previously asked question.  I suggest you revert, ask your new question in a new thread, and link back to this one.

Comment: @SamNead I understand your point, and in general I agree with you, however, this is not a separate question. I have a feeling, that triangulations with only 4 vertices could be planar, and if there are no spherical 4-valent planar graphs without double connections and cycles of length 2 + odd, then it could lead to a prove, that there are no triangulations without edge degree 2. And this comment/side question could help maybe.

Comment: What does this mean: "If one represents this triangulation as a graph"? Do you mean the one-skeleton? Or the dual one-skeleton? Note also that a triangulation is not determined (in general) by the homeomorphism type of its one-skeleton.

Comment: Also, note that if $T$ is a triangulation satisfying (a) and (b) (no need for the other hypotheses) then its one-skeleton $T^{(1)}$ is planar.

Comment: @SamNead I'm not sure what is the proper word for the dual graph. The graph that you get is if you draw every tetrahedron as a vertex and every face as a link between vertices. Then the triangulation I'm interested in becomes a 4-valent graph. Are you saying, that (a) and (b) ensure, that this graph is planar?

Comment: Your graph is called the "dual one-skeleton (for the given triangulation)".  I am saying that (a) and (b) ensure that the original one-skeleton is planar.

Comment: I've deleted an answer which I now think is broken. I glued two solid tori along their boundaries, but I now think that this gluing gives a lens space $L(3,1)$, not an $S^3$.

Comment: Combined with Sam Need's triangulation of $\mathbb{RP}^3$, this seems like any argument to rule out $S^3$ would have to be subtle, since $H_1(L(3,1)) = \mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_1(\mathbb{RP}^3) = \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$, there is no particular homology group which is acting as an obstacle.

Comment: Here is a paper that deals with small triangulations of $\mathbb{RP}^n$: https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.02703 and here is one that shows a lower bound for their method: https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.14358.

Comment: @domotorp thank you! I will check them out.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some observations that might be useful: not an answer, but too long for a comment.

---

The Euler characteristic of $S^3$ is zero (this holds for any compact three-manifold without boundary).  So we have $0 = V - E + F - T$.

By hypothesis we have $V = 4$.  Thus $4 = E - F + T$.  In any triangulation (of a three-manifold) every tetrahedron gives us four faces, and every face meets two tetrahedra.  We deduce that $F = 2T$.  Thus we have $4 = E - T$.

Let $E_k$ be the number of edges with degree $k$.  So $E = \sum E_k$.  From the definition of degree we have $6T = \sum (k \cdot E_k)$.  All edges have positive degree.  (So $E_0 = 0$.)  By hypothesis we have that $E_2 = 0$.  Non-degeneracy gives us the following.

**Claim:** All edge degrees are even.

**Proof:** Suppose that $e$ is an edge of degree $k$.  Suppose that the endpoints of $e$ are the vertices $v_0$ and $v_1$.  Suppose that  $t_0, t_1, \ldots, t_{k-1}$ are the tetrahedra (in order) meeting $e$.  Thus the vertices of the edges of $t_i$ not meeting $e$ are $v_2$ and $v_3$.  These alternate as we walk around $e$.  Thus $k$ is even. $\square$

Note that
$$
4 = E - T = \sum \left(1 - \frac{k}{6}\right)E_k
$$
Thus there are at least some edges with degree four. (This can also be seen by noting that triangulations of $S^2$ must have some vertices of degree less than six.) Finally, since $6T = \sum (k \cdot E_k) \geq 4E$ we have that $3T \geq 2E$.  Thus $4 = E - T \leq E - \frac{2}{3}E = \frac{1}{3}E$ and so $12 \leq E$.  Similarly, $8 \leq T$.

---

Inspired by the equalities $V = 4$, $T = 8$, and $E = 12$, we recall that the boundary of the [cross-polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope) is a triangulation of $S^3$ having $8$ vertices, $24$ edges, $32$ faces, and $16$ tetrahedra.  There is a natural (orientation-preserving) involution on the boundary of cross-polytope induced by the antipodal map on $\mathbb{R}^4$.  The quotient is a triangulation of the real projective space with $4$ vertices, $12$ edges, $16$ faces, and $8$ tetrahedra.

That is, there is a triangulation of *some* three-manifold obeying all of the desired combinatorial hypotheses.  Thus to prove that there is no such triangulation of $S^3$ we would actually need to use some further property of $S^3$ (such as the fact that it has trival $H_1$ or trivial $\pi_1$.)

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by something. By the end you write 6T >= 4E ; however at start, we have T = 2 and E = 6, so I'm actually confused by this inequality.

Comment: And what is the situation with k = 6? Does it mean, that practically we could have infinitely many edges of degree 6, so if we have a solution, and there could be many solutions for any E_6 ?

Comment: When you write "at start" you are thinking of the "initial configuration" which has edges of degree two.

Comment: I see, so If we assume that E2 = 0, then your inequality must be true.

Comment: Regarding your question about $E_6$: for any compact connected three-manifold $M$ and for any $n$ there is a triangulation of $M$ with at least $n$ edges of degree six.  People sometimes think of edges of degree less than six as giving some "positive" curvature, edges with degree greater than six as giving some "negative' curvature, and edges of degree six as (sort of) "flat".

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be a long one. I believe I now have a triangulation of the $3$-sphere with $28$ tetrahedra, $56$ triangles, $32$ edges and $4$ vertices, obeying all of the rules.

Our triangulation will be built from $7$ torii, nested one inside the other, as in this picture that I stole from [Martin Fernandez Cufre](https://chaotopia.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/hiperesfera-dzogchen/):

[image]

Number the torii as $T_1$, $T_2$, ..., $T_7$.
I'll refer to $T_1$ as the "innermost torus" and $T_7$ as the ``outermost". So, for each $T_i$, I can talk about the "interior of $T_i$" and the "exterior of $T_i$", each of which is a $3$-fold with boundary $T_i$.
The torii $T_i$ and $T_{i+1}$ are identified along vertices and along certain edges, but their triangles are all distinct.

Each $T_i$ has $4$ vertices, $12$ edges and $8$ triangles, and they are all isomorphic as abstract simplicial complexes.
However, I want to explain not only what the $T_i$ look like as abstract triangulations of the torii, but how they are nested inside each other.
In the diagrams below, I have unwrapped each of the tori unto a square; glue the sides of the square together to get the torus back.
The horizontal sides of the square will become contractible in the interior of $T_i$, and the vertical sides will become contractible in the exterior of $T_i$.
The same letter always indicates the same vertex.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'll now describe the regions between the torii.

### The interior of $T_1$:

In the figure below I have redrawn $T_1$ with arrowheads on some of the edges and numbers inside the triangles. The two edges with single arrow heads are glued together (in the direction shown by the arrowhead), as are  two edges with double arrow heads.
The triangles numbered $1$ form the faces of a tetrahedron, as do the triangles numbered $2$.

[image]

This three dimensional figure thus has boundary $T_1$, and the horizontal paths around $T_1$ become contractible in this figure.

### The region between $T_1$ and $T_2$

In the figure below, I have redrawn $T_1$ and $T_2$ with numbers in the triangles. For each number, the four triangles with that number form the faces of a tetrahedron.
Glue these together, identifying vertices with the same name and the corresponding edges, to make a three dimensional figure with two boundaries, 0ne which is $T_1$ and the other of which is $T_2$.
We have drawn an edge dashed if it is in only one of the two torii, and solid if it is in both.

[image]

This one is relatively easy to visualize, because we can overlay the diagrams on each other.
Note that two edges are now completely surrounded: The edge in $T_1$ with the single arrowheads is surrounded by tetrahedra $(1,2,4,6)$, and the edge with double arrow heads is surrounded by tetrahedra $(1,2,3,5)$.

### The region between $T_2$ and $T_3$

This one is hard to visualize.
Here are $T_2$ and $T_3$ labeled with the same rules as before: the numbers on the triangles are the forces of the tetrahedra; solid edges are in both $T_2$ and $T_3$; dashed edges are in just one.

[image]

The challenge is to see that the solid edges form isomorphic graphs on the two tori.
In the picture below, we have redrawn the figures above with new fundamental domains:

[image]

Hopefully, it is now clear that we can glue in tetrahedra between these two surfaces.

Between $T_4$ and $T_3$ we do the same thing as between $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Between $T_{8-i}$ and $T_{8-(i+1)}$, we do the same thing as between $T_i$ and $T_{i+1}$, but reflected over the northeast/southwest diagonal line.
Similarly, to fill the exterior of $T_8$, we use the pattern that we used inside $T_1$, reflected over that same diagonal.

I'll start the process of drawing the dual graph and leave the rest to you. Let $v_i$ be the vertex dual to the $i$-th tetrahedron.
Comparing the two ways that we have numbered the triangles of $T_1$, we see that each of $\{ v_1, v_2 \}$ borders each of $\{ v_3, v_4, v_5, v_6 \}$.
Comparing the two ways that we have numbered the triangles of $T_2$, we see that $(v_3, v_7, v_6, v_{10}, v_5, v_9, v_4, v_8)$ forms an octagon (in that order).
Hopefully, that's enough to get you going. I don't think it is planar.

I leave it to you to track the edges and check that each one is in at least $4$ tetrahedra. :)

Comment: Even though it didn't answer the question, I thought your other answer was interesting too, so I don't think it needed to be deleted.

Comment: @SamHopkins I will have to check it thoroughly, thank you for the update, I think I can read it a bit easier than before the edit!